# How to attach a javascript SDK in a react app by avoiding window object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got a web app written in React js in which I need to integrate a javascript SDK as documented in [this link](https://sift.com/developers/docs/curl/javascript-api/overview)

The sample code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _user_id = 'al_capone'; // Set to the user's ID, username, or email address, or '' if not yet known.
  var _session_id = 'unique_session_id'; // Set to a unique session ID for the visitor's current browsing session.

  var _sift = window._sift = window._sift || [];
  _sift.push(['_setAccount', 'INSERT_BEACON_KEY_HERE']);
  _sift.push(['_setUserId', _user_id]);
  _sift.push(['_setSessionId', _session_id]);
  _sift.push(['_trackPageview']);

 (function() {
   function ls() {
     var e = document.createElement('script');
     e.src = 'https://cdn.sift.com/s.js';
     document.body.appendChild(e);
   }
   if (window.attachEvent) {
     window.attachEvent('onload', ls);
   } else {
     window.addEventListener('load', ls, false);
   }
 })();
</script>
```

Now, I'm aware that I should not use `window` object in React app however this sample code requires me to attach an object to the window object.

I have created a function to add the script:

```
function createSiftScript(sift_script_ele) {

  //attach the object array to the window
  var _sift = window._sift = window._sift || [];
  _sift.push(['_setAccount', SIFT_SCIENCE_BEACON_KEY]);
  _sift.push(['_setUserId', email]);
  _sift.push(['_setSessionId', setUniqueSessionId()]);

  //attach the external script
  sift_script_ele = document.createElement("script");
  sift_script_ele.setAttribute('id', SIFT_SCRIPT_ID);
  sift_script_ele.setAttribute('type', "text/javascript");
  sift_script_ele.setAttribute('src', "https://cdn.sift.com/s.js");
  document.head.appendChild(sift_script_ele);
}
```

And a function to set the object on the window as [suggested for SPAs like mine build in React/Angular](https://support.sift.com/hc/en-us/articles/208370598):

```
export function pushEventsToSift() {
  _sift.push(['_trackPageview']);
}
```

I'll call these functions in all the pages wherever needed however, accessing the `window` object looks dirty to me.

My question is:

If you would be doing this SDK integration in a React SPA then how would you have approached it by following the cleanest approach?

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't touch the DOM elements in React's care then you're safe in terms of it integrating with React. Regarding setting it on the page, you could throw it directly in `index.html`, there's nothing stopping you.

If you want it on specific pages - though wasn't this an SPA? - then you can throw the config in a React element [as per their docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) which should return an empty div or something that React never touches afterwards; But you'll still need to clean up the window object manually .